# Java Date returned value is not that which was returned

Tags: java, maven, tycho

I've been modifying the [tycho_buildtimestamp_svn](https://github.com/Zune01/tycho_buildtimestamp_svn) maven plugin to more suite our needs. Everything is going well and the `getTimestamp()` routine is returning the expected `Date`.

However, once back in the tycho-packaging-plugin ([BuildQualifierMojo.java](https://github.com/eclipse/tycho/blob/master/tycho-packaging-plugin/src/main/java/org/eclipse/tycho/buildversion/BuildQualifierMojo.java)) we experience an occasional incorrect date.

I've managed to isolate it and is now well beyond my understanding, reduced code as follows:

```
private TychoProjectVersion calculateQualifiedVersion() {
    ...
    if (qualifier == null) {
        Date timestamp = getBuildTimestamp();
        System.out.println("Getting Qualifier: " + timestamp.toString());
        qualifier = getQualifier(timestamp);
    }
    ...
}

protected Date getBuildTimestamp() throws MojoExecutionException {
    ...
    Date dt = provider.getTimestamp(session, project, execution);
    System.out.println("Returning: " + dt.toString());
    return dt;
}
```

The result:

```
Returning: Wed Feb 24 05:23:48 EST 2016
Getting Qualifier: Tue Feb 21 06:10:00 EST 2017
```

Out of the 300 or so bundles build, this might only affect 10-20 of them, but it is consistent and repeatable every time with the same bundles and same dates.

EDIT: Someone mentioned attempting:

```
Date result = new Date(dt.getTime());
return result;
```

This did not help.

EDIT2:

I included `String.valueOf(System.identityHashCode(x))` in to the logging statements. The result showed that for those bundles that are working correctly, the same Date object is used for the first and second SysOut call, but on those which are failing, it is a different object:

```
Returning: Wed May 25 02:15:35 EDT 2016  (821373005)
Getting Qualifier: Tue Feb 21 06:10:00 EST 2017  (1739646104)
```

I was also able to determine that in all cases, the plugin bundle type works, and only feature bundles fail, but not all feature bundles.

Comment: Juat to understand, the same Date Object prints in 2 different ways ?

Comment: Apparently not. I used `String.valueOf(System.identityHashCode(timestamp))` and got two different results. Will update the question.

Comment: But in the code you posted it IS the same Date object, printed in 2 different methods..there's something missing?

Comment: Agreed... hence this StackOverflow question :) On Monday I'll be testing more with changing to passing `long`s around instead of `Date`s to see if that helps. I will also be trying to add `synchronize` to several methods too.

Comment: mmmh so you mean you have concurrent executions ? In this case it may be that you print the dates from 2 different executions. Why don't you put an execution id in the print ?